# Flask - Registration for new user doesn't work - Bad request

Tags: python, flask

I am doing some app with Flask and I am working on registration now. I am working with SQL and not SQLAlchemy on this case (just to work with SQL a bit more)
Also using Flask-WTF for forms.

I successfully create database table:

```
class RegisterForm(Form):
    name = StringField(
    'Username',
    validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=25)]
    )
    email = StringField(
    'Email',
    validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=6, max=40)]
    )
    password = PasswordField(
    'Password',
    validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=6, max=40)])
    confirm = PasswordField(
    'Repeat Password',
    validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password', message='Passwords must match')]
    )
```

In my views.py I have next for registration:

```
@app.route("/register/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm(request.form)

    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():

        name = request.form["name"]
        email = request.form["email"]
        password = request.form["password"]

        g.db.connect_db()
        g.db.execute("INSERT INTO users(name, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?)", (name, email, password))
        g.db.commit()
        g.db.close()
    return render_template("register.html", form=form)
```

And my simple form:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
            {{ form.csrf_token }}
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="usernameInput">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="usernameInput">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="emailInput">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="emailInput">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="passwordInput">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="passwordInput">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="confirmInput">Confirm password</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirm" class="form-control" id="confirmInput">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Register</button>
              {% if error %}
                <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{error}} </p>
              {% endif %}
            </form>
```

Now I have been trying, changing and fixing for 2 days and can't find a problem. When I enter all the data and click Register I get 400 Bad request.
Perhaps it something silly and I just can't see it.

If anyone can help, I would appriciate.
If need more info or code, let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is posting to `/`, not `/register/`.

You haven't shown the route you defined for `/`, but presumably it does not accept POSTs.

Comment: Okey, great I get it now, thanks:)
Would you know what this means:
AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'db' ?

Comment: Presumably it means your `g` object, whatever it is, does not have anything called `db`. If you want more help though you should post a new question with the full code of how you're setting that up.